# How to update an input value while dragging a row?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, html-table

I have a form with a table in it. The table has several rows.

```
<table id="sortable">
    <tbody class="ui-sortable">
        <tr>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Sort</th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="ui-state-default" style="">
            <td><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="id1" value="12">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="name1" value="Apple">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="price1" value="1.95">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="sort1" value="1">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="ui-state-default">
            <td><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="id3" value="9">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="name3" value="Banana">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="price3" value=".95">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="sort3" value="3">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="ui-state-default" style="">
            <td><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="id2" value="15">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="name2" value="Pear">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="price2" value="2.95">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="sort2" value="2">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5">
                <input type="submit" value="submit">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Using jQueryUI I can drag the rows with the following script:

```
$(function () {
    $("#sortable tbody").sortable();
    $("#sortable tbody").disableSelection();
});
```

I currently can drag the rows but now I also want to change the `sort` input in the process.

So if I was to drag the third row to the top, they should change places and the number in the `sort` input.

I haven't found a way to use jQueryUI to make this work. In the example on the jQueryUI site they are using `list`s instead of `table`s.

Is this possible? 
If not what would be a better way?

Here is the [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/rUg5M/)

Comment: What are the business rules, seeing I can specify any random number. Let's say I have `row 1` with sort `5`, `row 2` with sort `1` and `row 3` with sort `7` and say a `row 4` with sort `3`. When I drag `row 3` into position 1 what order is now expected in the sorts? I'm assuming you want the sort order to be the same all the time no matter where the rows are place or are sort values connected to the row they are set on?

Comment: I need the sort order to corispond to what ever position it is in. So row 1 is 1, 2 is 2, and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just interested in keeping the same sort values after the drag-drop than before you can use the [**start**](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-start) and [**stop**](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-stop) events of `sortable`, similar to this:

```
$(function () {
    var sortOrder = [];
    var $sortableTable  = $("#sortable tbody");

    $sortableTable.sortable({
        start: function(event, element){
            $.map($('[name^=sort]', $sortableTable), function(element){
                sortOrder.push(element.value);
            });
        },
        stop: function(event, element) {
            $.each($('tr [name^=sort]', $sortableTable), function(index, element){
                element.value = sortOrder[index];
            });
        }
    });

    $sortableTable.disableSelection();

    $('tr [name^=sort]', $sortableTable).on('keydown', function(){
        $(this).closest('tr').data()
    });
});
```

Using an additional variable you can store the current sort values on `start` and re-apply them on `stop`.

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/wc9dN/) - re-set sort to what is was before drag-drop

---

If you need to apply a different business logic that's fine, either use the same events and apply your own logic or use any of the other [**available events**](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/) as needed.

> I need the sort order to corispond to what ever position it is in. So
>   row 1 is 1, 2 is 2, and so on.

The sort being an editable input was confusing then but if that is all you want then don't use the `start` event and only use the `stop` and re-set the values each time, similar to this:

```
stop: function(event, element) {
    $.each($('tr [name^=sort]', $sortableTable), function(index, element){
        element.value = index+1;
    });
}
```

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/5yB2U/) - Re-set sort positional

---

Comment: @DougSteinberg: Running both fiddles in Chrome all sort values get updated no matter which element you drag. What browser are you running the examples in?

Answer (score 0):

I was working on this just to come back to see it had been answered.  This answer is a little different however as it adjusts the values while being sorted.

```
var sort;
$(function () {
    $("#sortable tbody").sortable({
        change: function( event, ui ) {
            //alert(ui.helper.find('td input[name^=sort]').val(7));
            sort = 0;
            $('#sortable tr.ui-state-default:not(".ui-sortable-helper")').each(function(){
                sort++;
                if($(this).hasClass('ui-sortable-placeholder'))
                    ui.helper.find('td input[name^=sort]').attr('name','sort'+sort).attr('value',sort).val(sort);
                else
                    $(this).find('td input[name^=sort]').attr('name','sort'+sort).attr('value',sort).val(sort);
            });
        }
    });
    $("#sortable tbody").disableSelection();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/trevordowdle/rUg5M/1/

Comment: @DougSteinberg can I get some feedback on my answer?  Thanks